# Energy and momentum

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, mass, momentum

Does a muon or an electron with the same energy have the higher momentum?
According to $E^2=m^2+p^2$ if you increase the restmass, the momentum must decrease.

But if we look at a nonrelativistic case:
$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$
with an example like:
$E_1=10kg*(10\frac{m}{s})^2=E_2=1000kg*(1\frac{m}{s})$
$p_1=100\frac{kg*m}{s}<p_2=1000\frac{kg*m}{s}$

but because $E=0.5mv^2$ is a good approximation in nonrelativistic cases, it should be true here. And so should the general energy momentum relation.

So where is our mistake? How can the momentum of the heavier object be bigger and smaller at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a false comparison. You are computing two different energies.

In the relativistic case, when you you write $$E^2=m^2+p^2, $$
for a single particle, the energy term is the sum of the kinetic energy and the mass energy: $$E=K+m.$$

In the non-relativistic situation you have defined the energy simply as the kinetic energy and ignored the contribution of the mass energy. What you should do is equate the kinetic energies and look at the momenta in both situations.

In the relativistic (I will include the c terms), solving for $p$ you get$$
p=\frac{1}{c}\sqrt{K^2+2Kmc^2}.$$

You can do the numerical comparison.